# Matrix representation for generators of the Fuchsian group of the three-holed sphere.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Let $P$ be a three-holed sphere with its usual presentation
$$ \pi_1(P) = \langle U, V, W | UVW=1 \rangle. $$

A hyperbolic structure on $P$ is given by a Fuchsian representation $\rho:\pi_1(P) \to \operatorname{PSL}(2, \mathbb{R})$.

That is $\rho(U), \rho(V)$ and $\rho(W)$ are now represented by matrices subject to the condition that $\rho(U) \rho(V)= \rho(W)^{-1}$ imposed by the presentation of $\pi_1(P)$.

I am reading a paper in which the author finds that
$$\rho(U) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{a/2} &  \kappa \\ 0 & e^{-a/2} \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$ \rho(V) =  
\begin{pmatrix} e^{-b/2} &  0 \\ 1 & e^{b/2} \end{pmatrix}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the respective lengths of the boundaries $U$ and $V$.

I know that since $\rho(U)$, $\rho(V)$ and $\rho(W)$ are hyperbolic elements of $\operatorname{PSL}(2, \mathbb{R})$, there exists a $\operatorname{PSL}(2, \mathbb{R})$-conjugation such that $\rho(U) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{a/2} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-a/2} \end{pmatrix} $ and similarly for $\rho(V)$.

However, how were the above matrix representations including the terms $\kappa$ (resp. $1$) obtained?

Comment: wouldn't work a process of diagonalization for them?

Comment: Are you asking how the author obtained those things? Or are you just asking for any derivation of them?